# Need DC wiring help

Tags: dc, wiring, lcd

I planned to use the SATA to 5 V cable to power the LCD control panel board, but there are two 5 V pins on the board so which one should I solder?

Images of the board:

[image: board1]

[image: board2]

Link to the LG monitor manual: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/833473/Lg-Flatron-L1753s.html

p/s: does my monitor power require 5V or 12V?

Comment: Either. They are in parallel. You tell us what it requires for voltages.

Answer (score 0):

> but there are two 5 V pins on the board so which one should I solder?

These two pins are connected, when you look on the copper on the PCB.

So the answer is: to both, someone decided that a single contact hadn't a sufficient capacity.

> p/s: does my monitor power require 5V or 12V?

Certainly looks like it has contacts for both, so both Why would you think it only needs either when it clearly has a supply that supplies both?

> I planned to use the SATA to 5 V cable to power the LCD control panel board

Make very sure your actual video source has the same understanding of "ground" as your SATA ground. Otherwise, you're risking high ground currents. (The supply for the screen was possibly isolated, so that this never becomes an issue)

Comment: Thank you for answering 
I think 12V is for the monitor's backlight, which will not reuse. So the monitor should be on with only 5V right?
I'm doing something like this: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vv1xwH6PGrg)

Comment: no, not "right". "Unanswerable", "what you do is just wildly guessing".